# Update attribute by Ajax Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, radio-button

I have a form with two radio buttons, each one have it's own value, like this:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: ship_df_product_path(@product), remote: true do |f| %>

    <td><%= radio_button_tag 'ship', @product.ship_df %> Envío dentro DF - $<%= @product.envio_df %> </td>

    <td><%= radio_button_tag 'ship', @product.ship_int %> Envío interior del país- $<%= @product.envio_int %></td>

        <%= f.text_field :shipping, :class => "span2", :style => "display:" %>

<% end %>
```

The problem is that I need to update the ":shipping" attribute of the @product object depending of which one is clicked.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use radio_button tag

```
<td><%= f.radio_button 'ship', @product.ship_df %> Envío dentro DF - $<%= @product.envio_df %> </td>

<td><%= f.radio_button 'ship', @product.ship_int %> Envío interior del país- $<%= @product.envio_int %></td>
```